# Why Openpyxl changes background color of all charts in the sheet to white

Tags: python, openpyxl

i would like to know why Openxlpy changes all background color charts to white in this simple code. Inserts data correctly but all colors are changed.

```
def insert_data_excel():
    try:
        wb = load_workbook(filename=FILE_NAME)
        ws = wb[SHEET_NAME]
    except:
        print("Error opening .xlsx file")

    ws.cell(column=1),row=location, value="test") 
    wb.save(filename=FILE_NAME)
    wb.close()
```

Comment: This warning from [the docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) might be related: *openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are opened and saved with the same name*

Comment: You need to share with us which version of Python and openpyxl you are using. As it is your code is not supposed to change the cell styles. Also, your action (`ws.cell(column=1),row=location, value="test")`) should not be within the except clause.

Comment: Hello Dror. Python version = 3.8.2. Sorry, i've changed the code. My code should not modify any style but it does. I don't know why

Comment: You should also add the `Exception` youre trying to catch (I assume `FileNotFoundError`) and you have a redundant `)` in `ws.cell(...)`. However, I can't reproduce your error, when I try it my formatting stays the same. Are you modifying cells in other places in your code? Plus, which version of `openpyxl` do you use?

Comment: If you think there is a bug then you should submit an issue on the openpyxl bug tracker. The code here is totally irrelevant when it comes to charts.

Comment: It seems a bug guys, i am going to open an issue to bug tracker. Thanks